# Unstack and reorder pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've searched around but couldn't find a solution for how to unstack and reorder a pandas dataframe.

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': [1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
                   'band': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'val': [0.18, 0.19, 0.20, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 0.26, 0.27]})
```

I can group by `'type'` and `'band'` to get the mean across both dimensions, and use `unstack()` to show `'band'` as columns:

```
df.groupby(['type', 'band']).mean().unstack(level=1)
```

My question is, how can I reorder the columns so that they're in descending (or more generally, any arbitrarily sorted) order?

The output looks like this:

```
    val
band    A   B           C
type            
1   0.215   0.230000    0.210
2   0.240   0.223333    0.235
```

What I want is the following:

```
    val
band    C   B           A
type            
1   0.210   0.230000    0.215
2   0.235   0.223333    0.240
```

In practice, I have many more than 3 columns.

Comment: @ayhan I personally want to just do descending sort, but I was just asking how to generalize it for curiosity. One could imagine sorting based on some function, but I don't have a particular example in mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you want [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on the columns:

```
df.groupby(['type', 'band']).mean().unstack(level=1)\
    .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Result:

```
        val              
band      C      B      A
type                     
1     0.210  0.230  0.215
2     0.235  0.223  0.240
```

As for an arbitrary order: say your order is "C, A, B".  Generally, you must just specify this directly.

```
order = list('CAB')
df[order]
```

Comment: If you have multiindex columns, you may need to pass `level=...` too. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html).

Answer (score 2):

The output of `df.groupby(['type', 'band']).mean().unstack(level=1)` is another DataFrame. You can do the following:

```
df = df.groupby(['type', 'band']).mean().unstack(level=1)
df = df.reindex_axis(sorted(df.columns, reverse=True), axis=1)
```

Comment: I think this method would allow arbitrary sorting as you can pass in a `lambda` function to `sorted`.

Comment: @pault sure, you can pass a `key` function to sorted